# How to configure function of login(); with GET request?

Tags: javascript, php, json, get

He everyone!This is my code,but PHPSTORM said me that I have errors

```
 function login() {
  if (isset($_GET['login'])) && (isset($_GET['oldPassword'])){
   {
      echo $_GET['login'];
      echo $_GET['oldPassword'];
  } else {
      // Fallback behaviour goes here

$login = login($_GET['login']);
$password = login($_GET['oldPassword']);
}
```

Maybe something is not correct.Here screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4lAF.png)

Comment: The IDE is literally telling you what your syntax errors are in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong code.

That is true then:

```
function login()
{
    if (isset($_GET['login']) && isset($_GET['oldPassword'])) {

        echo $_GET['login'];
        echo $_GET['oldPassword'];
    } else {
        // Fallback behaviour goes here

        $login    = login($_GET['login']);
        $password = login($_GET['oldPassword']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup)